# Collecting information on where user clicks inside the app

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have created an `iOS` app using `Swift` to be used for a research project.
This app will pretty much only run on one specific device (iPhone7) and be used while the interviewer asks the user some question and the user uses the app to perform some tasks.

I would like to collect some statistics when the app is being used.
More precisely, I want to understand where the user actually clicks inside the app! I want to improve the User Interface and could use this data to see what buttons are being used and what buttons are not used.

I did some googling and came across some tools that pretty much claim to have this functionality, such as [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/?cpnid=701b0000000W1Gz), [UXCAM](http://uxcam.com/) and [Google Analytics](https://www.google.se/intl/en/analytics/#?modal_active=none).

I was wondering if there are any open source/free alternativ (SDK) to these paid solutions or should I start making something on my own from scratch.

The phone runs the app is also not connected to internet so the options above are not really suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The free version of Google Analytics has a Mobile SDK, but it's in the process of being phased out in favor of a recent Google acquisition: Firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/features/analytics/

If you need this level of tracking for a research project, the free version of Firebase is more than likely to meet your needs.

Comment: please see updated question, the phone is not connected to internet.